# Skip line reading file with string::getline in C++

Tags: c++, fstream, stdstring

I'm using the following code to get lines out of a file until "#" is not found. It works, but I don't understand why *it gets the same line twice*. How do I avoid it, i.e., skip a line after string::find(...) has been called?

```
do {
    getline(file, line);
} while(line.find("#") != string::npos);
```

Comment: Please add a little more code so that your question can be better understood.

Comment: *it gets the same line twice* — why do you think so?

Answer (score 1):

Simply put, it doesn't.

You're not performing any checks whatsoever for end-of-input.

It's only after the *second* iteration, and the *second* call to `getline`, that EOF is set on the stream and the `.find()` operation fails.

**The EOF flag is *not* set when EOF is reached, but after an attempt to read past EOF fails.**

Write this:

```
do {
} while (getline(file, line) && line.find("#") != string::npos);
```

Oops! Now your loop body is empty, and there are much better ways of writing this.

Perhaps:

```
while (getline(file, line) && line.find("#") != string::npos)) {}
```

That's better. =)

Answer (score 0):

You should check if you have reached the end of your file before you check the string it returns.

```
do {
    getline(file, line);
} while(file.good() && line.find("#") != string::npos);
```

Comment: You should do `while (std::getline(file, line) && line.find("#") != std::string::npos) {...}`

Comment: @0x499602D2 What difference do I get if I do that?

Comment: Well, using `file.good()` as your condition is wrong, as retrieving input is not designed to be done in such a way. Moreover, creating an entire block simply to put `getline(..)` is unnecessary.